# Como hago un popup en mi app de django en el admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin

Tengo problemas necesito hacer una cargar de animales (toro, vaca, ternero) donde todos tienen algo en comun pero cada cual tiene campos diferentes, lo que necesito es hacer que al seleccionar el animal haga un popup o me dirija hacia un formulario que ya tengo creado en models 
estos son los models que tengo cargados y necesito en la app[image: esta es la idea]

```
class CargarAnimal(models.Model):
    TIPOANIMAL = (('T','Toro'), ('V', 'Vaca'), ('T','Ternero'))
    categoria_animal = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = ``TIPOANIMAL, default = 'V')



class Animal(models.Model):
    id_caravana = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    trazabilidad = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    raza = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    edad = models.IntegerField(max_length = 3)
    peso = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    origen = models.CharField(max_length = 35)



    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: %s Categoria: %s Raza: %s' % (self.id_caravana, `self.categoria, self.razayy`)

class Vaca(Animal):
    #animal = models.OneToOneField(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lote_actual = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    ESTADOSREPRODUCTIVO = (('P', 'Preñada'), ('V', 'Vacia'))
    estado_reproductivo = models.CharField(max_length =1, 
                                choices = ESTADOSREPRODUCTIVO, `default='V')`
    fecha_probable_parto = models.DateField()
    estado_vaca = models.BooleanField(default = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: %s Trazabilidad: %s Raza: %s Categoria: %s Edad: %d Peso: %s \
            Origen: %s Lote Actual: %s Estado Reproductivo: %s \
            Fecha probable de parto: %s ' % \
            (self.id_caravana, self.trazabilidad, self.raza,
                self.categoria, self.edad, self.peso, self.origen,
                self.lote_actual, self.estado_reproductivo, self.fecha_probable_parto)

class Toro(Animal):
    #animal = models.OneToOneField(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lote_anterior = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    lote_destino = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    cultivos = models.CharField(max_length = 35)
    circunferencia_escrotal = models.CharField(max_length = 35)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: %s Trazabilidad: %s Raza: %s Categoria: %s Edad: %d Peso: %s \
            Origen: %s Lote anterior: %s  Lote destino: %s Cultivos %s Circunferencia escrotal: %s' % (self.animal.id_caravana, 
            self.trazabilidad, self.raza, self.categoria, self.edad, self.peso, 
            self.origen, self.lote_anterior, self.lote_destino, self.cultivos, self.circunferencia_escrotal)
```

Comment: Que llevas al momento?

Comment: llevo la imagen que se ve y los models ya creados

Comment: Necesito que apartir del primer models cargarAnimal me dirija hacia el model vaca /toro